# i want my cube will not extend through the ground.How to do this?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a ground and a cube, both have rigidbody and colliders. My cube is situated upper than my ground. I did management by cube using keys(for example i press 'S' and my cube fall down on 1). The problem is than my cube touches ground and i press 'S' it extends through my ground. Who knows how to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well...a simple solution can be to set a min value on that axis for the cube.
for example, something like that:

```
if(Input.GetButton("S")) //move object when u press S
{
    //in this way your cube can move only if it's over the ground  
    if(cube.y > ground_y)  
    //your code to translate the cube
}
```

so if your colliders fail for some reason you have an additional check.

Comment: Ok, thanks so much!!! It works. But what the reason, i mean why does my cube extends through my ground if i have rigitbodies and colliders?

Comment: cause your cube is kinematic and kinematic object doesn't use physics, so it doesn't use colliders : )

Comment: I turned off iskinematic for my cube and ground, but the result is bad. My cube is still able to be extended through the ground (i mean without using first answer). Whats the reason, its hard to undersatand?!

Comment: If your ground collider is thin, that can be the source of an issue, because as soon as you force through another collider on it, that will start "sinking in" and falling out at "gravity end". On top of that, transform.translate ignores physics, so that's not the right way to move around objects AND assume colliders will work properly. You need to use AddForce instead, or implement code segments like in the answer above (i.e. verify if you didn't break any of your rules -collision- while you ignored physics and moved around a rigidbody)